# PHP require_once not recognised

Tags: php

I'm newbie on PHP and I'm not sure why the 'require_once' is not working.
Both PHP files are located in the same directory and another PHP file which is the same DIR is working correctly with the same 3 lines.

```
 <?php
        
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $aResult = array();

    if( !isset($_POST['functionname']) ) { $aResult['error'] = 'No function name!'; }

    if( !isset($_POST['arguments']) ) { $aResult['error'] = 'No function arguments!'; }

    if( !isset($aResult['error']) ) {

        switch($_POST['functionname']) {
            case 'delete_monument':
                if( !is_array($_POST['arguments']) || (count($_POST['arguments']) < 1) ) {
                    $aResult['error'] = 'Error in arguments!';
                }
                
                else {
                    $dir = '[PRIVATE DATA]' . urldecode($_POST['arguments'][0]);

                    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
                    foreach($files as $file) {
                        if ($file->isDir()){
                        rmdir($file->getRealPath());
                        } 
                        else {
                            unlink($file->getRealPath());
                        }
                    }
                    rmdir($dir);

                    //Clean database
                    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'setup.php';
                    SigPlusNovoDatabaseSetup::update();
                    SigPlusNovoDatabaseSetup::populate();

        
                    $aResult['result'] = $dir;
                }              
                break;         
               
              
            default:
                $aResult['error'] = 'Not found function '.$_POST['functionname'].'!';
                break;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($aResult);

?>
```

I checked other posts but nothing seems to be my problem. Can someone help me?

Thx.

Edit:

I wrote this lines at the top

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and checked the PHP error log, but no errors are displayed :/

Comment: What specific error / problem are you experiencing? Please [edit] the question with more info. See also [ask].

Comment: try `require_once ('setup.php');`  or `require_once (__DIR__.'/setup.php');`

Comment: also, make sure the name is indeed `setup.php`

Comment: No error is displayed, the code breaks at that point. I also tried require_once ('setup.php'); and require_once (__DIR__.'/setup.php');

Comment: What does "breaks" mean? Describe the specific behaviour you experience. And have you turned on PHP error logging, and checked the log file for errors/warnings? https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting . See also [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: Another possibility - have you already `require`d or `include`d this file earlier in your code? If so then, as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) it won't be included again - that's the whole point of the "once" in the name.

Comment: When I use the 'required_once' the code stops at that point. I'll investigate how to turn on error logging. This file wasnt included before in my code

Comment: `and checked the PHP error log`...the settings you've used there will enable error reporting in the output of the script, not logging to a file

Comment: I noticed it, even so I forced an error and it was displayed correctly

Comment: Ok so then probably the options are a) require_once is never actually executed, 2) as i suggested above, it's already been included previously somewhere in the script (or chain of included scripts) and therefore won't be included again, or 3) possibly setup.php contains some code which causes the script to halt without showing an error.